# RemoveChild removes only last element of nodelist but never the first one

Tags: javascript, dom

Hello i am developing slider on javaScript. At first i am creating 3 cards on init then on click to the rigth arrow i c am creating next 3 cards and previous cards need to be removed. so i using a removeChild(slider.childNodes[i]) hovewer it deleting only new cards that i add and leaves old ones, also i tried slider.removeChild(slider.firstChild and lastChild) bu it didnt help eather. here is the code

```
import { pets } from '/js/pets-list.js';

const arrowLeft = document.getElementById('arrow-left');
const arrowRight = document.getElementById('arrow-right');
const mobArrowLeft = document.getElementById('mobile-arrow-left');
const mobArrowRight = document.getElementById('mobile-arrow-right');

const slider = document.getElementById('slider');

let sliderPositionLeft = slider.style.left;

for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    let newCardR = document.createElement('div');
    newCardR.className = 'slider-content_card';

    let newCardImg = document.createElement('img');
    newCardImg.src = 'assets/modal-images/woody.png';
    newCardImg.alt = 'slider-pet-image';

    let newCardText = document.createElement('p');
    newCardText.textContent = 'Woody';

    let newCardButton = document.createElement('button');
    newCardButton.className = 'button_secondary';
    newCardButton.textContent = 'Learn more';

    newCardR.appendChild(newCardImg);
    newCardR.appendChild(newCardText);
    newCardR.appendChild(newCardButton);

    slider.appendChild(newCardR);
}

let clickCounterR = 0;

arrowRight.addEventListener('click', () => {
    clickCounterR++;
    console.log(slider.childNodes);
    for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        debugger;
        let newCardR = document.createElement('div');
        newCardR.className = 'slider-content_card';

        let newCardImg = document.createElement('img');
        newCardImg.src = 'assets/modal-images/woody.png';
        newCardImg.alt = 'slider-pet-image';

        let newCardText = document.createElement('p');
        newCardText.textContent = 'Woody';

        let newCardButton = document.createElement('button');
        newCardButton.className = 'button_secondary';
        newCardButton.textContent = 'Learn more';

        newCardR.appendChild(newCardImg);
        newCardR.appendChild(newCardText);
        newCardR.appendChild(newCardButton);

        slider.appendChild(newCardR);
    }
    if (clickCounterR === 2) {
        debugger;
        for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            slider.removeChild(slider.firstChild);
        }
        clickCounterR = 0;
    }
    sliderPositionLeft = sliderPositionLeft - 1004;
    slider.style.left = sliderPositionLeft + 'px';
});
```

Comment: There is now just a `.remove()` method that will remove the current element you call it on.

Comment: The code you posted is calling `.removeChild()` on the first child of the "slider" node. There's no reason that should not work. What exactly is your evidence that that code is not working? Are there errors reported? Does it *ever* work?

Comment: When you are calling `removeChild(slider.childNodes[i])` with an incrementing `i` (like you said in your question) this will remove the first, third and fifth child of the original children. But the code you are showing will remove the first there children, no matter what

Comment: @derpirscher Both `append` and `remove` methods are inside for loops, so three new `cardR`s are being appended and three elements are being removed.

Comment: @Rojo yeah noticed that, that's why I deleted my comment

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
elementToRemove.remove();
```

With `element.remove()` rather than `parent.removeChild(element)`, you won't have to worry about applying the method on the parent element or using correct indices.

Answer (score 0):

Since your code is removing the new elements first, you should try removing the old cards first, and *then* add the new cards (so, switch your two for loops around):

```js
arrowRight.addEventListener('click', () => {
    clickCounterR++;
    console.log(slider.childNodes);
    if (clickCounterR === 2) {
        debugger;
        for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            slider.removeChild(slider.firstChild);
        }
        clickCounterR = 0;
    }
    for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        debugger;
        let newCardR = document.createElement('div');
        newCardR.className = 'slider-content_card';

        let newCardImg = document.createElement('img');
        newCardImg.src = 'assets/modal-images/woody.png';
        newCardImg.alt = 'slider-pet-image';

        let newCardText = document.createElement('p');
        newCardText.textContent = 'Woody';

        let newCardButton = document.createElement('button');
        newCardButton.className = 'button_secondary';
        newCardButton.textContent = 'Learn more';

        newCardR.appendChild(newCardImg);
        newCardR.appendChild(newCardText);
        newCardR.appendChild(newCardButton);

        slider.appendChild(newCardR);
    }
    sliderPositionLeft = sliderPositionLeft - 1004;
    slider.style.left = sliderPositionLeft + 'px';
});
```

Comment: Why do you think a different order of operations would help? If you append at the end and remove from the front, it doesn't make any difference...

Comment: @derpirscher OP said that the code is removing the new nodes that are supposedly being appended to the end. There must be something changing the order, or OP is poorly describing the initial HTML. Just something for OP to try.